# Error when using Google Play LVL

Tags: java, android

I followed this tutorial: http://twistbyte.com/tutorial/using-the-android-licensing-service-step-by-step

It doesn't seem to work.

I get an error/suggestions saying "get unimplemented methods" at `protected class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {`.  It doesn't seem to work.  Can someone please provide some insight?  If it helps, I am using Eclipse  Thanks!

Comment: You're probably not implementing everything in `LicenseCheckerCallback` properly.

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: Well, it shows that when your not `@override`ing all the methods in an interface. When you click it eclipse will add them for you.

Comment: How do I do that?  When I add @Override eclipse tells me to remove them.

Comment: Are you sure it says `Get unimplemented methods`? My eclipse shows `The type ... must implement the inherited abstract method ...` and offers the option to `Add unimplemented methods`.

Comment: Yes, your Eclipse is correct.  How do I fix that?

Comment: Just click on `Add unimplemented methods`.

Comment: I do that, but then it just gives me empty methods with public void applicationError(int errorCode) {

Comment: What did you expect it to do? It even has an explanation - `Error in application code. Caller did not call or set up license checker correctly. Should be considered fatal.`

Comment: It just creates more issues.  It seems like there is an issue with the tutorial.  Ill see what I can do.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The tutorial implements that method. I don't see any issue with it.